# How to handling IllegalStateException in rxjava and kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I'm making an application using rxjava and kotlin. I understand how it works but I have a problem with the handling error problem. I need to handle IllegalStateException in case the response is failed. The complete JSON response is like this :
[image]

but if I input a wrong phone number or wrong password the response is like this :
[image]

I alreay made a class ErrorHandler to get an error and process it. this is how i call the response :

```
 disposables.add(endPointServices.login(map)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({
                login ->
            if(!login.sTATUS.toString().equals(AppConstant.FAILED))
            {
                status200(login)
                view?.moveActivity()
            }
            else
            {
                view?.setMessage(login.mESSAGE.toString())
            }
        }, {t: Throwable? ->
                ErrorHandler.handlerErrorPresenter(getView(),t!!)
        }
        )
    )
```

But I need to show the message from response just in case user type a wrong password or wrong phone number. Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Comment: cant understant your question . does this  `I need to show the message from response`  means. `login.MESSAGE` ? what it has to do with `IllegalStateException`

Comment: yes, that's true I need to show login. message whether JSON response is complete or not. But retrofit assume it as an error then it throws IllegalStateException and I can't get anything from JSON response except the error

Comment: I think your issue is  `JSONObject`  and `JSONArray`  . when you receive error your parsing failed because of empty `JSONArray`

Comment: yes I know it, I just need how to keep show login. message whether the response is an error or not. but I can't show it because of error